# Why can't I read the device's deviation from the magnetic North with this code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, magnetometer

OK the code is now working, but it still needs work. The values I get are "sticky", they are not stable (the magnetic North seems to move a bit every time I try to return to it), and I need to shake the device a bit in order to refresh/wake-up the values..

Game.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "CoreLocation.h"

@interface Game : NSObject

<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property BOOL stopButtonPressed;

-(void) play;

@end
```

Game.m

```
@implementation Game

- (id) init 
{
    self = [super init];

    self.stopButtonPressed = NO;

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;

    return self;
}

-(void) play 
{

    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading]; 

    while(!self.stopButtonPressed)
    {
         double degrees = locationManager.heading.magneticHeading;

         int degreesRounded = (int)degrees;

         NSLog(@"Degrees : %i", degreesRounded);
    }
}

@end
```

MyViewController.m

```
@interface MyViewController()
{
    Game *game;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    game = [[Game alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)playPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    [game performSelectorInBackground:@selector(play) withObject:nil];
}

- (IBAction)stopPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    game.stopButtonPressed = YES;
}

@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will block the thread, and if it's happening in the main thread, you will never get the button press.

**CLLocationManager is an asynchronous mechanism**. To work with it properly, you must provide a delegate which it will notify when updates to location are available (this can be `self` in most cases (where `self` is a viewController or similar). See [CLLocationManagerDelegate docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate)

```
...
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
}

- (void)locationManager:manager didUpdateHeading:newHeading {
    double degrees = newHeading.magneticHeading;
     NSLog(@"Degrees : %F", degrees);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be blocking the main thread, I get "Heading is available" on the console and then I just keep getting "Degrees : 0.000"

Comment: Right, in an infinite loop. It's not frozen, it's just that this code won't let anything else occur.

Comment: I'm also executing all this in a -(void) play method that runs in a separate thread : '[game performSelectorInBackground:@selector(play) withObject:nil];'

Comment: Ah, so it's not blocking the `main` thread, which means you can still press the button and get out of that loop. Better; but the essence of the answer remains your best option: leverage the CLLocationManagerDelegate Callbacks :-)

Comment: I edited my original post and included the whole of my code so that you can have a better picture of what I'm doing. I'm new to Obj-C and I'm not sure how delegating works. I'll try to implement your code in mine and see what I get..

Comment: Is this part : CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading]; supposed to go in my -(id) init in Game.m ??

Comment: It is far more common to put code like that into a ViewController, and leave your `Game` to it's own domain. The delegate needs to conform to the appropriate protocol (add `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>` to it's `@interface` line). However, if location updates are vital to your "Game", then it may be better for the `Game` to be the delegate in this case (then add the delegate methods to `Game` class and set it as the delegate on locationManager)

Comment: hmm... you lost me there.. have to check the documentation again although it's not very helpful.. more confusing actually.. it just presents methods assuming you know where everything goes...

Comment: Edited my original post and replaced it with working code. It's still not perfect but I'll save the rest for a different Question I guess.. Please tell me whether there is something wrong with this new version.. Thanks!

Comment: I would remove the while loop, and instead implement the `- (void)locationManager:manager didUpdateHeading:newHeading` method in `Game`. This method, if you implement it, will be called automatically when the location information becomes available. It's pretty slick if you're new to asynchronous programming, and a far better approach than what I see there (in fact, if you do that, you don't need to fork your own thread)

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the `CLLocationManager` delegate methods instead of calling the properties directly: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate